# Google Maps - KML fusiontable query error

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a fusiontable which is a merge of a polygon kml and spreadsheet. According to Google documentation my query should work but it does'nt. It never loads and google display this error message: "Data may still be loading. Drag or refresh the page to find out". If I load the page without query it works but the layer style (color and opacity) set in the fusiontable throught Google Drive is not displayed. What is the problem with google tablefusion ?

```
layer_mun = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({     
    query: {
      select: 'geometry',
      from: '1Nrj1Yka8RQ3RW9QlERbOqJnw9Bq2vbFWlAJ0eeQ',
      where: "CODE_CS LIKE '%722000%'"
    }
});
layer_mun.setMap(map);
```

Comment: from my experience it sometimes takes a moment for things to sync up. though you can always try to recreate the table if it goes on for too long (mutiple hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the column names in [your table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Nrj1Yka8RQ3RW9QlERbOqJnw9Bq2vbFWlAJ0eeQ)
CODE_CS should be Code_CS

[example](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S840401nswi)

Comment: thank you! I didnt know it was case sensitive. Do you know why the style defined in google Drive is not kept in Google Maps API?

Comment: see [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/11c79a6de456a967/0e1253d25c182960?lnk=gst&q=styleId#0e1253d25c182960) on the Fusion Tables Users Group (among [others](http://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/search?group=fusion-tables-users-group&q=styleId&qt_g=Search+this+group))

Comment: The links work for me:  see styleId in the documentation: 
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingStyles